# Python memory leak in class?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-requests

I have been working on a scraper that gets information from a real estate API. 
This is written as a class with key functions (renamed):

```
myclass.execute_search
myclass.clean_data
myclass.upload_to_database
myclass.wrapper
```

myclass.wrapper executes in the constructor, and performs execute_search, clean_data and upload_to_database sequentially. execute_search utilises requests to send and retrieve data from the API. There are also a couple of member variables which are initialised and then used to execute the search.

All this works perfectly when I execute the class as a single instance in this form:

```
myclass(postcode)
```

However, if I place the code in a loop, the data from the previous search leaks into the next one. So each subsequent execution through the loop, the data that is uploaded to the database includes the data from all previous executions of the loop. By the time I loop through all 500 postcodes, the last postcode search will dump over 10000 results onto the server even though there are in reality only about 40 results.

```
for postcode in postcodes:
    print(postcode)
    mydata = myclass(postcode)
    gc.collect()
    del mydata
    time.sleep(6)
```

I have attempted to remove this leak by adding the gc.collect() and del mydata statements but this hasn't resolved the leak. I have double checked that there are no global variables in the file at all. I have also explicitly defined a destructor function but to no avail.

```
def __del__(self):
    self.data = []
```

I am relatively new to python (from c++) and am not certain if I am doing something wrong with my use of classes. I can use a workaround in the SQL database by adding DISTINCT on the retrieved record keys but this is obviously not ideal.

Unfortunately I cannot paste the entire class on this forum as the API is private. Below is the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, postcode, bedrooms_min=None, bedrooms_max=None, carspaces_min=None, carspaces_max=None,
             price_min=None, price_max=None, search_mode='buy', recursive=True, logging=True):
    self.q_postcode = postcode
    self.q_bedrooms_max = bedrooms_max
    self.q_bedrooms_min = bedrooms_min
    self.q_carspaces_min = carspaces_min
    self.q_carspaces_max = carspaces_max
    self.q_price_min = price_min
    self.q_price_max = price_max
    self.q_search_mode = search_mode
    self.q_recursive = recursive
    self.logging = logging
    self.requesttime = datetime.datetime.now()
    # ensure id is unique to database
    self.check_uniqid()
    # execute function after initialising variables
    try:
        self.execute_search()
    except:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        self.error = ''.join(line for line in lines)
    if self.logging:
        try:
            self.cleandata()
            self.upload_toserver()
        except:
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
            self.error = ''.join(line for line in lines)
        self.update_main_log()
```

Comment: The problem is likely in your definition of `myclass`, perhaps a mutable default argument.

Comment: Can you post the myclass code? The problem is definitely there

Comment: What have you coded in the `__init__` method of the class? Your are probably handling wrong the variable. You need it to be re-initialized at every instatiation. A note: using garbage collection in Python is a very rare occurence, so you probably don't need it in this case. Just create the class, run the method and the class is gced automatically when the pointers counter go to 0.

Comment: Ah worked it out thanks. I needed to re-initialise data to `[]` each time in the constructor. That isn't quite the behaviour I am used to!